# Random forest with Grid Search having worst performance than simple Random Forest

Tags: python, model, random-forest, sklearn-pandas, grid-search

I am training a model using a simple Random Forest and then another model with the exact same dataset with Random Forest using Grid Search. Supossely , since Grid Search looks for the best combination of values ,the perfomance of the later one should be higher, but the opposite is happening.

```
#Random Forest
clf=RandomForestClassifier()
model=clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred=model.predict(X_test)

#Model metrics
results=classifmodel_Metrics('rf',model, y_test, y_pred)
list_of_results.append(results)

#GridSearchCV

clf=RandomForestClassifier()
parameter_grid={'n_estimators':[50,100,150,250,500,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000],
                'max_depth':[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
gridSearch=GridSearchCV(clf,parameter_grid,cv=5,n_jobs=1,verbose=5)
gridSearchResults=gridSearch.fit(X,y)

print(gridSearchResults.best_estimator_)
clf=gridSearchResults.best_estimator_
model=clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred=model.predict(X_test)

#Model metrics
results=classifmodel_Metrics('rfopt',model,y_test,y_pred)
list_of_results.append(results)

print(list_of_results)
```

Does anyone know why is this happening? Is something wrong with my code or is something that can esporadically happen?
The function I use to calcule my model performance is this , being F1 the value I use for reference( the higher the F1 the best the model is)

```
def classifmodel_Metrics(modelName, model, actual, predicted):

    classes = list(np.unique(np.concatenate((actual,predicted))))

    confMtx = confusion_matrix(actual,predicted)

    print("Confusion Matrix")
    print(confMtx)

    report = classification_report(actual,predicted,output_dict = True)

    precision = report["macro avg"]["precision"]
    recall = report["macro avg"]["recall"]
    f1 = report["macro avg"]["f1-score"] # Média ponderada da precision e recall

    res = pd.Series({
    "ModelName":modelName,
    "Model":model,
    "accuracy":round(accuracy_score(predicted,actual),3),
    "precision": round(precision,3),
    "recall": round(recall,3),
    "f1": round(f1,3)
    })

    if len(classes) == 2:
        print("\naccuracy: {0:.2%}".format(round(accuracy_score(predicted,actual),3)))
        print("\nprecision: {0:.2%}".format(precision))
        print("\nrecall: {0:.2%}".format(recall))
        print("\nf1: {0:.2%}".format(f1))
    else:
        print("\n",classification_report(actual,predicted))

    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your parameter grid is just not capturing enough depth for your model to learn well.

You have:

```
parameter_grid={'n_estimators':[50,100,150,250,500,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000],
                'max_depth':[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
```

Where you are limiting your model to at most 64 leaves (2^6) through having a max depth of 6. In contrast, the default for scikit-learn is have as many layers as necessary until each of your *n* samples is in its own leaf (<*n*/2).

To improve performance I would use more depth options. It's also highly unlikely that you need so many trees in your forest (diminishing returns). Try something like this instead:

```
parameter_grid={'n_estimators':[64, 128, 256],
                'max_depth':[2, 4, 8, 16, 36, 64]}
```

If your best model is topping out the max depth, you can try increasing the limit you are testing.